# Django GET request params from POST request

Tags: python, django, url, request

I have a form that you need to fill out using a POST request, but I want to the result to be a redirection to various pages on my site. Sometimes I want the user to be redirected to a profile page, sometimes to a purchase page.

So I put the redirect URI in the GET params of the URL of the form page that POSTs:
/form/?redirect_uri=/payments/

The url is correct upon landing on the forms page, with the appropriate redirect_uri. However, when I fill out the form and POST, Django doesn't seem to think there are any params in the GET request.

How can I get those params from the URL out on a POST request?

EDIT:

```
def form_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Do stuff with form validation here
        redirect_uri = "/home/"
        if "redirect_uri" in request.GET:
            redirect_uri = request.GET['redirect_uri']
            if redirect_uri == request.path:
                # avoid loops
                redirect_uri = "/home/"
        return redirect(redirect_uri)
```

This form page is loaded by accessing this url:

```
/form/?redirect_uri=/payments/
```

Form:

```
<form action="/form/" method="POST" class="wizard-form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" autocomplete="off">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email or username" required>
            </fieldset>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Show us your code. It is possible to get the `GET` params from any request.

Comment: Ok I added the code. I've debugged and the check that is failing is "redirect_uri" apparently is not in request.GET.

Comment: What is the output in console if you `print request.GET['redirect_uri']` at the top of that function?

Comment: That's an multi key dict value error. It's saying that "redirect_uri" is not in request.GET, which is absurb. The full URL of the form page I'm on is:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/form/?redirect_uri=/payments/

Comment: Also, if I look at the output in my terminal, it shows this:
[16/Jun/2016 03:52:59]"GET /form/?redirect_uri=/payments/ HTTP/1.1" 200 
[16/Jun/2016 03:52:59]"POST /form/ HTTP/1.1" 302

No redirect uri??

Comment: please add your form

Comment: Done, added the form. Maybe the form "action" attribute needs to include the ? params too?

Comment: Your form `action` is `action="/form/"`, and this is the URL that the form will get POSTed to. If you want the GET param in the POST, then you need to include it in the `action`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your form has to be modified as follows:

```
<form action="/form/?redirect_uri={{ request.GET.redirect_url}}"
    method="POST" class="wizard-form"
    enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" autocomplete="off">
```

Permit me to also suggest a slight optimization to your view

```
def form_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Do stuff with form validation here
        redirect_uri = request.GET.get('redirect_uri',"/home/")
        if "redirect_uri"  == request.path:
                # avoid loops
                redirect_uri = "/home/"
        return redirect(redirect_uri)
```

Comment: Ah forgot about the .get notation, this is way better. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the POST request - i.e. when you submit the form - the url will be what you specified in the `'action'` attribute in the form. If the parameters you require are not there, your view will not get them.

So either update your forms's `action` attribute to have these parameters or alternatively you can add thin in the form itself (as hidden inputs).

In GET request you will get attributes from url that you see in the browser.